# what exactly were the nephilim

Tags: genesis, angels, nephilim, giants

I know that there are several different interpretations of the term "Nephilim" found in Genesis 6, and was wondering about the identity of these Nephilim. The four main views I found are as follows:

1. That the Nephilim are the offspring of angelic beings physically coming down to earth and procreating with human women
2. That the Nephilim are the offspring of angelic beings possessing human men and procreating with human women
3. That the Nephilim are the offspring of the godly line of Seth having children with ungodly women
4. That the Nephilim are the offspring of godly men procreating with ungodly women

These four views seem to be fairly equal in adherents, but I was wondering if there were any alternate views and what biblical/extrabiblical evidence is put forward to support them.

Comment: see the Catholic study bible for details on ancient legends and fables like those.